# Android AppTileService onClick not get called

Tags: android, android-service, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

For my android app I have added an AppTile. Most of the time this AppTile **is not clickable**. Its icon is grayed out, such as disabled or unavailable icons (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/Tile.html#STATE_UNAVAILABLE)

In my Logs this line is never reached

```
Logger.d(getClass(), "onClick()");
```

But I have tested that the methods *onStartListening()* or *onStopListening()* are called every time the AppTile becomes visible or hides.

AppTileService.java

```
package my.package

import android.os.Build;
import android.service.quicksettings.TileService;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;

import my.package.utils.Logger;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class AppTileService extends TileService {

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        Logger.d(getClass(), "onClick()");
        if (isSecure()) {
            Logger.d(getClass(), "isSecure = true");
            NotificationHandler.showDirectReplyNotification(this);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="my.package"> 
   <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".AppTileService"
            android:icon="@drawable/tile_icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Can someone tell me what this could be, or whether I have forgotten something to implement?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to indicate that the tile is active, in one of two ways.

First, your `<service>` could have `<meta-data android:name="android.service.quicksettings.ACTIVE_TILE" android:value="true" />`.

Second, in `onStartListening()`, you can update the tile state to be active, as I do by means of an `updateTile()` method in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.5/Introspection/SAWMonitorTile) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android):

```
  private void updateTile() {
    Tile tile=getQsTile();

    if (tile!=null) {
      boolean isEnabled=
        getPrefs()
          .getBoolean(SettingsFragment.PREF_ENABLED, false);
      int state=isEnabled ?
        Tile.STATE_ACTIVE :
        Tile.STATE_INACTIVE;

      tile.setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this,
        R.drawable.ic_new_releases_24dp));
      tile.setLabel(getString(R.string.app_name_short));
      tile.setState(state);
      tile.updateTile();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added your suggestion and must remove the tile once and re-add it to the quick settings. Now it works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add that although the answer marked as the solution is **a** correct solution, it does not fit the question's case and doesn't truly solve the problem described.

[Android documentation states](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService#META_DATA_ACTIVE_TILE) that the `ACTIVE_TILE` metadata is only for a TileService that should handle its own custom listener lifecycle, and not if you want the Tile to begin listening when the quick settings drawer is opened.

**Rather, the solution requires:**

**1)** The default state for `Tile` is `STATE_UNAVAILABLE` (Value 0x00), which does not respond to click events unlike the active and inactive states. Instead, in `onTileAdded()` and/or `onStartListening()`, you should update the tile state to Active or Inactive with:

```
 Tile tile = getQsTile();
 tile.setState(Tile.STATE_ACTIVE);
 tile.updateTile();
```

**2)** `super.onClick();` should be included in your `onClick()` implementation.

I made this mistake and was confused as to why my Tile was inconsistently responding to taps. But after tracking when `onStartListening()` and `onStopListening()` was called, the above meta tag should not be used if you simply want the Tile to run a task after the user taps it. Using it without implementing `requestListeningState()` will result in some odd behavior such as the Tile not properly listening for user click.

Comment: What you've said is theoretically correct. Unfortunately, this doesn't work on some customized OS, such as ColorOS by OPPO, and OxygenOS by OnePlus. I've tracked when the `onStartListening()` is being called on OnePlus Devices and I found it is not always being called when the user dragged down the notification panel. OxygenOS sometimes prevents it from being called to save the battery. However, if I whitelist my app from OnePlus's battery optimization settings, `onStartListening()` is always being called when the user dragged down the notification panel.

Comment: I only encounter this problem on OPPO devices but not in any AOSP. Eventually, I tried the solution by @CommonsWare and it works. Looks like `ACTIVE_TILE` hasn't been polluted by the OPPO battery saver. So I switch to `ACTIVE_TILE` and handle the lifecycle by myself with `requestListeningState()` even if my tile just runs a task after the user taps it.